# How to extend a layout without overwriting the scripts in the layout section (Laravel 5.8)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Ths should be simple enough, but...

I have a layout view dashboard-layout.blade.php with:

```
@section('headscripts')
  <script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>      
@show
```

And a billing.blade.php view that extends the layout file:

```
@extends('layouts.dashboard-layout')

@section('headscripts')
  @parent
  <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/dropin/1.17.2/js/dropin.min.js"></script>
@endsection
```

The problem is, this only outputs the first script...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `@stack` tag to add script not `@section`.

Comment: Have you tried by clearing the view using command: `php artisan view:clear` ?

Comment: well, this is embarrassing...turns out the code I posted actually works, the problem was rendering the wrong view in the controller #facepalm still, thanks for your help

Comment: try `@yield('headscripts')` instead

Comment: Why not use another name (e.g. `additional-headscripts`) and add the `@yield('additional-headscripts)` tag below the main one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `@stack('name here')` instead of `@yield('name here')`

and use

```
@push('name here')
 // Add Your Script Here
@endpush
```

instead of

```
@section('name here')
   // Scripts
@endsection
```

to solve your problem.